# Can I force Windows 11 to spread the load to non hyper-threading cores?

Tags: cpu, windows-11, amd-ryzen

I'm using an AMD Ryzen 7950X with 16 cores. With Simultaneous Multithreading (SMT), Windows 11 recognizes it as having 32 virtual cores. My application, a chess engine, benefits from multiple cores but doesn't utilize virtual cores effectively. It runs faster on 16 separate physical cores rather than on 32 virtual cores, as the latter scenario causes each virtual core to slow down due to shared resources.

Previously, on other cpu, when I ran the application with a thread count equal to or less than the CPU's core count, the load was evenly distributed across all physical cores. However, with my new 7950X, I've noticed a different behavior. When I run 16 threads, Windows seems to assign them to virtual cores 0-16, which correspond to physical cores 0-7, leaving cores 8-15 idle. This appears to be an attempt by Windows to keep processes within a single Core Complex Die (CCD), which might be beneficial for some applications, but not for mine.

[image: Only half processors are used]

As a result, my application performs about 40% slower because its 16 threads are only using 8 physical cores.

I've considered setting process affinity to alternate between even or odd-numbered cores, but I'd prefer not to. Other parts of my application can benefit from SMT and it's a tedious to have to change the afinity each time I start the application.

Is there a way to modify or disable this behavior to better utilize the physical cores of my Ryzen 7950X for my specific use case?